# How to custom output a media paragraph from within a custom block?

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a two-column custom block type that has two fields `field_content_left` and `field_content_right` which are entity reference revisions to allow the use of my other paragraph types.

One of my referenced paragraph types is a media one which allows for your standard media.

For my particular case, when I create a twig template file for this specific block (`block--homepage-blk-1.html.twig`) and use `{{ content.field_content_left }}`, the image that I placed in my left column is placed and that's great.

My only issue is that it's displaying it in the default media/image format of `Large (480x480)`.

Is there a way from within this custom block twig template for me to grab the image data and then override it with my other custom image format of `homepage`? I've tried different things with kint like `{{ kint(content.field_content_left[0]['#paragraph'].field_media[0])` to try and access the image but can't seem to get there.

Any suggestions? Am I looking at this the wrong way? Let me know if there is a better way to go about this or if I can access all the data I need (the image/alt/image URL + overriding image style).

---

My code in that part of the block currently looks like this but want to override that left section in order to customize how the image will look on the homepage.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
        {{ content.field_content_left }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 mx-auto my-auto">
        <h2 class="mb-4">{{ content.field_block_title }}</h2>
        {{ content.field_content_right }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using code, you could try to create a special `homepage` view mode for the media entity. This new view mode uses the `homepage` image format for the image field. After that, on the parent entity, change the view mode on the referencing field to use the `homepage` viewmode on the media.

Comment: As a general scheme, in all my projects there I have lot of media entity view modes, which all have the same machine name as a corresponding (responsive) image format, and use exactly that image format as image field formatter setting. So e.g. if I create a `hero_banner` responsive image format, I also create a corresponding `hero_banner` media entity view mode. In paragraphs or custom content blocks, I select those view modes for the media field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better start with the `block_content` entity to get the paragraph entity and then the media entity:

```
{% set paragraph = elements.content['#block_content'].field_content_left.entity %}
{% set media = paragraph.field_media.entity %}
```

Now you can render the image:

```
<img src="{{ file_url(media.field_media_image.entity.uri.value) }}">
```

For image styles you need the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{% set image_uri = media|file_uri %}
{% if image_uri is not null %}
  {% set alt = media.field_media_image.alt %}
  {% set title = media.field_media_image.title %}
  <p>Image rendered via image.html.twig:
  {{ drupal_image(image_uri, 'thumbnail', {alt: alt, title: title}) }}
  </p>
  <p>Image tag placed directly in the block template:
  <img src="{{ image_uri|image_style('thumbnail') }}" alt="{{ alt }}" title="{{ title }}">
  </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you @4uk4! I did have the twig tweak module installed so this is exactly what I was looking for. Works exactly as needed and thanks for the multiple options.